# Control width of element in CarouselView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a CarouselView in my app. Within my CarouselView, I have a label with a long text.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="65*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout SnapPointsAlignment="Center" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalItemSpacing="20"/>
       </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
       <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Frame VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Accent" Grid.Column="1">
                       <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                           <Label Text="{Binding TextExample}"/>
                       </StackLayout>
                   </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
       </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</grid>
```

I realized, that no matter what I do, the width of CarouselView `Frame` is controlled by the length of the text in the label - which means, that the `Frame` exceeds the boundaries of the view.

I can though set the `widthrequest` of the frame to a desirable width, which will cause the text in the label to wrap, thus meaning that the width of the `Frame` doesn't exceed the boundaries of the view. Unfortunately, I would much rather prefer to control the width of the Frame by a relative width-percentage to the view - Which I have tried to do in the above code.

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine on my side with static data (the text in label will warp).So you can provide a screenshot of your device or emulator .

Comment: Try to make a longer sentence of text! Then i guess you will experience a problem similar to me.

Comment: In my sample, the length of text is long enough.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Share your sample which contains your issue and I will test it on my side:) Don't forget to remove your personal info,such as password or account ID.

Comment: I have provided the complete code for the view - there is nothing else to show. - I run it in a pixel 3 XL emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:** You seem to have forgotten to set the width of `DataTemplate`. So ,the width of grid is controlled by the length of the text in the label .

**Solution:** From your code , you seem to let the width of `DataTemplate` equals the width of screen. So you can binding the width in code behind .

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="contentPage"   // set the name of the contentpage
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage">
```

```
<Grid WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.Width}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Frame VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Accent" Grid.Column="1">
         <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                 <Label Text="{Binding xxx}"/>
         </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

#### in Share Project App.xaml.cs

```
public static double ScreenWidth;
public static double ScreenHeight;
```

#### in Android MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental", "Visual_Experimental", "CollectionView_Experimental");
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

   App.ScreenWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 
   App.ScreenHeight =Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 

   LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

#### in iOS

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    //...
    App.ScreenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
    App.ScreenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
    //...
}
```

#### in Code Behind or ViewModel

```
public double Width { get; private set; }

//...

Width = App.ScreenWidth;
```

Answer (score 4):

The Solution of Lucas Zhang pointed me the right way, although it has some drawbacks. First it requires a lot of Code behind in App and ViewModel, and the main flaw is that it is not responsive, i.e. when the user turns his screen.

It is much easier to name the `CarouselView` and then bind the `DesiredWidh` of the `DataTemplate` directly to the `Width` of the `CarouselView`.

```
<CarouselView HeightRequest="200" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems" 
              x:Name="ctlCarousel">
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <ListItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsAlignment="Center" SnapPointsType="Mandatory" />
    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference ctlCarousel}, Path=Width}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Frame HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Hello World!</x:String>
            <x:String>This is a very long string</x:String>
            <x:String>Card 3</x:String>
            <x:String>Test 123</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
</CarouselView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use relative layout and set width of frame relative to width of any view